# How do i writeln() this

Tags: string, pascal

How do I writeln() a string that has a single quotation mark? Something like this:

`writeln('It's a cat')`

It will think that 'It' is a string it need to print out and s is an identifier so how do I fix it? It's on Pascal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double the quote to escape it.

```
writeln('It''s a cat');
```

Alternately, you can embed the character value to substitute it:

```
writeln('It'#39's a cat');
writeln('It' + #39 + 's a cat');
```